# Python turtle mouse does not follow directly

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

How do you make turtle move without using `turtle.goto(x,y)` but `turtle.speed(speed)` and `turtle.heading(angle)`? I need this for a game I am making. Where the mouse is, I want to make it go in that direction. But when I change it, it goes to that place then to my mouse:

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.title("Test")
screen.bgcolor("white")
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)

ship = turtle.Turtle()
ship.speed(1)
ship.shape("triangle")
ship.penup()
ship.goto(0,0)
ship.direction = "stop"
ship.turtlesize(3)
turtle.hideturtle()
def onmove(self, fun, add=None):
        if fun is None:
            self.cv.unbind('<Motion>')
        else:
            def eventfun(event):
                fun(self.cv.canvasx(event.x) / self.xscale, -self.cv.canvasy(event.y) / self.yscale)
            self.cv.bind('<Motion>', eventfun, add)
def goto_handler(x, y):
    onmove(turtle.Screen(), None)
    ship.setheading(ship.towards(x, y)) #this is where you use the x,y cordinates and I have seat them to got to x,y and set heading
    ship.goto(x,y)
    onmove(turtle.Screen(), goto_handler)

onmove(screen, goto_handler)
```

If you only `setheading` and `speed` it just turns that way and does not move. If you try this code it works -- it is just that I use `ship.goto(x, y)` which makes it go to `(x, y)`. But when you change your mouse when it is moving, it first goes to `(x, y)` then to your new mouse position. I pretty much just want it to just follow the mouse but I can not do that.

Comment: You use ```self``` as a param name, was this originally OOP? You define ```eventfun``` inside an ```if statement```, do you mean to do this or is your indentation incorrect?

Comment: @JoshuaNixon, the `self` parameter is because I originally wrote this so it could be installed as a method of `TurtleScreen`, or a subclass, or used stand-alone.  (@jujumumu, where's your upvote on the answer you got this from!)  The `def` under the `if` is intentional as we're either setting or clearing this handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the code below gives you the motion you desire.  It only uses `onmove()` to stash the target's position and uses an `ontimer()` to aim and move the turtle.  It also stops when the target has been enveloped:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, Vec2D

def onmove(self, fun, add=None):
    if fun is None:
        self.cv.unbind('<Motion>')
    else:
        def eventfun(event):
            fun(Vec2D(self.cv.canvasx(event.x) / self.xscale, -self.cv.canvasy(event.y) / self.yscale))

        self.cv.bind('<Motion>', eventfun, add)

def goto_handler(position):
    global target

    onmove(screen, None)
    target = position
    onmove(screen, goto_handler)

def move():
    if ship.distance(target) > 5:
        ship.setheading(ship.towards(target))
        ship.forward(5)

    screen.ontimer(move, 50)

screen = Screen()
screen.title("Test")
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)

ship = Turtle("triangle")
ship.turtlesize(3)
ship.speed('fast')
ship.penup()

target = (0, 0)

onmove(screen, goto_handler)

move()

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Cdlane I used your code to find the mouse so thank you. It works if you have the speed really high it just stays under the mouse but in a video game it can not go that quick. the problem is that you are using .goto(x,y) which makes it o there before doing anything else. But i want it to be able to change where it is heading whenever the mouse changes position. Imagine you were playing a video game and this is what you used. Without changing the speed. It would be pretty weird. If you know a game called slither.io I want it like that motion. Not the snake but the snake head goes that direction.

Comment: @jujumumu, you've lost me -- there's no `.goto()` in the above code.  If you want it to go slower, reduce the '5' in `ship.forward(5)` and/or increase the '50' in `screen.ontimer(move, 50)`.  The turtle `speed()` may not be what you think it is -- it's about drawing delay but you're not drawing anything.